# Perturbation of Laplacian via Kato-Rellich theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory

Let's consider a potential $V(x)\in L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)$. I want to know if the following Hamiltonian 
$$-\Delta+V(x)$$
is self-adjoint on $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$.
 My idea is to use Kato-Rellich theorem; so for $f\in D(-\Delta)=H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ we have
$$\Vert Vf\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}\leq\Vert V\Vert_{L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)}\Vert f\Vert_{L^6(\mathbb{R}^3)}$$
Now I can use Gagliardo-Niremberg-Sobolev inequality to get
$$\Vert f\Vert_{L^6(\mathbb{R}^3)}\leq C\Vert\Delta f\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}^{\frac{1}{2}}\Vert f\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Now I can use Young inequality
$$\Vert f\Vert_{L^6(\mathbb{R}^3)}\leq C(\epsilon\Vert\Delta f\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Vert f\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)})$$
So we have that $V$ is bounded with respect to the Laplacian and so Kato-Rellich theorem gives the thesis.
Is there something worng in this reasoning?

Comment: Nope, every step is as legit as it can be. Plus, you might be interested by [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858224/non-examples-for-the-kato-rellich-theorem) on MSE.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the question, I do not know how you got the implication from Gagliardo Nuremberg Sobolev inequality, the way I do your thing is following $$||f||_6^2\leq C||\nabla f||_2^2$$ then I use young inequality in Fourier space, for R.H.S. as $||\nabla f||_2^2=|||\xi| \hat f(\xi)||^2\leq C(\epsilon |||\xi|^2 \hat f(\xi)||^2+\frac{1}{\epsilon}||\hat f (\xi)||^2) $. RHS gives you laplacian when you go back to Original space. I would be happy to see if you could elaborate how you got your conclusion.